# Add javascript confirmation popup on "Move to Trash" link

Tags: wp-admin

I want to open javascript error message when some one clicks on "Move to Trash" link in Publish box in wp-admin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open javascript popup on wp-admin publish/update button](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96716/open-javascript-popup-on-wp-admin-publish-update-button)

Comment: Whether it's the trash or publish/update button, @Sumit, this, IMHO, remains the exact same question. To say something constructive: Take a look at jQuery's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your `functions.php`:

```
if (! empty($GLOBALS['pagenow']) && 'post.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'])
    add_action('admin_footer', 'trash_click_error');
function trash_click_error() {
    echo <<<JQUERY
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#delete-action a').unbind();
        $('#delete-action a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Error!');
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    $('#save-action .spinner').hide();
                    $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                },
                1
            );
        });
    });
</script>
JQUERY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think we are very close to do it. I used 'wp_trash_post' instead of 'admin_footer'. It goes in this function but I am not able to get the alert box. Can you please help me to sort out it.

Comment: Well, that is beacuse the hook is the wrong one. If you don't want to use `admin_footer` (whatever the reason may be), use `admin_head` with a priority of 999 or something like this. Why is that so? We are injecting some jQuery code (to the website's source code) that then is affecting the link. There's no sense in doing this after the link has already been clicked (which is when you hook action is fired).

Comment: Hi,I need to apply same thing on Trash link on posts listing page. Any help much appriciated